# What is an intuitive explanation of the Bayesian score?

Tags: bayesian-network, scoring-rules

I am familiar with the [Bayesian score](http://kdbio.inesc-id.pt/~asmc/pub/talks/09-TA/ta_pres.pdf), which is used to compare competing structures of a BN. However, I have difficulty in understanding how the Bayesian score formula below is derived.

**1)** What is an intuitive explanation of the Bayesian score? (e.g. how do the fractions within the product operators equate to $P(D|B_S)$)

**2)** What type of structures does it favour? (e.g. more/less connected, higher/lower number of parents, etc.)

**Background:** The Bayesian score of a BN structure, $B_S$, for a data set, $D$, is used to calculate the joint probability of $P(B_S,D)$. For a discrete network (after some assumptions*),  it is given as:

$$P(B_S,D) = P(B_S)\prod_{i=0}^n\prod_{j=1}^{qi} \frac{\Gamma(N'_{ij})}{\Gamma(N'_{ij} + N_{ij})} \prod_{k=1}^{ri} \frac{\Gamma(N'_{ijk} + N_{ijk})}{\Gamma(N'_{ijk})} $$

- $\Gamma()$ is the gamma function. Above, since all counts are positive integers, $\Gamma(int) = (int-1)!$
- $P(B_S)$ is the prior on the network structure ( taken to be uniform/uninformative by many versions of the Bayesian score)
- $xi$ is a node in the network with $n$ nodes;
- $ri (1 ≤ i ≤ n)$ is the cardinality of $xi$;
- $qi$ denotes the cardinality of the parent set of $xi$ , that is, the number of different values to which the parents of xi, $pa(xi)$, can be instantiated.
- $N_{ij} (1 ≤ i ≤ n, 1 ≤ j ≤ qi)$ denotes the number of records in $D$ for which $pa(xi)$ takes its $j$th value.
- $N_{ijk} (1 ≤ i ≤ n, 1 ≤ j ≤ qi, 1 ≤ k ≤ ri)$ denotes the number of records in $D$ for which $pa(xi)$ takes its $j$th value and for which $xi$ takes its $k$th value. So, $N_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{ri} N_{ijk}$.
- $N′_{ij}$ and $N′_{ijk}$ represent choices of priors on counts restricted by $N'_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{ri} N'_{ijk}$.

*List of asssumptions: 1 - Multinomial Sample; 2- Parameter Independence; 3- Parameter Modularity; 4 - Dirichlet; 5- Complete Data